# Map depends on dynamic variable

Tags: angularjs

I have following hardcoded map:

```
$scope.lists = {
    test1: [
        {   name: 'My Name'  }
    ],
    test2: [
        {   name: 'My Second Name'  }
    ]
};

$scope.selectedList = "test1";
```

Then inside my pug/html file:

```
div(ng-repeat="list in lists.selectedList")
```

What I need is I want to have array to be selected depend on var of `selectedList`. Am I able to do that in AngularJS?

Comment: lists in not an array at all ...

Comment: well sorry, it's called as map in java lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use square-bracket syntax in angular attributes:

```
 div(ng-repeat="list in lists[selectedList]")
```

Comment: Thanks that's works! I missed this one that actually how it works in Java..